# Distribution of a transformation of a random variable

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, random-variable, probability-inequalities

[image]

I have started off by this:

$F_Y(Y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(X^2 \leq y).$ Now, I have been told that 
$P(X^2 \leq y) = P(- \sqrt y \leq X \leq \sqrt y) $. I don't quite understand why this is and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $X^2 \leq y = |X| \leq \sqrt{y} = -\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}$

What is the exact confustion that you are having here?

Answer (score 4):

Follow TenaliRaman's comment

$X^2\le y\Leftrightarrow |X|\le\sqrt{y}\Leftrightarrow -\sqrt{y}\le X \le \sqrt{y}$ and $y \in [0,1]$

$$F(y)=P(Y<y)=P(X^2<y)=P(-\sqrt{y}\le X \le \sqrt{y})=\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}|x|dx=\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{0}-xdx+\int_{0}^{\sqrt{y}}xdx=-\frac{1}{2}x^2\mid_{-\sqrt{y}}^{0}+\frac{1}{2}x^2\mid_{0}^{\sqrt{y}}=y$$

You can see $F(y)=y$ and $y \in [0,1]$

This shows $Y\sim U(0,1)$

Comment: This being a self-study question, providing the complete answer does not help the OP to figure out a working solution.

Comment: I agree with you. To fully answer Op's question, one may need start from definition of a random variable which is a set function then go to $\sigma$ field and Borel $\sigma$ field and also need to explain the probability defined on a set which may be more difficult to for me explain. So I take a easier way to solve the problem.

Comment: No, there is no any irony in my comments or answer. I respect you since you have given me very good suggests for my questions.

Comment: Also, when I have questions I really think if I post the problem to SE then people such as Xi'an, Wuber,  Glen, etc. would give me good suggestions.

Comment: Ok, good to hear! And sorry for the paranoia! What I meant is that we should help Kim by going stepwise in the answer so that she or he can spot his or her jamming blocks. For instance, starting only at $X^2<y$ being $|X|<\sqrt{y}$ being $X<\sqrt{y}$ and $X>-\sqrt{y}$.